# NSolve vs Roots

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I need to evaluate the following expression in Mathematica:

```
(1/((3 + E^(4 k))^8))
 2 (1 + E^(4 k))^2 k (729 + E^(24 k) + 210 k + 2 E^(20 k) (9 + 7 k) + 
4 E^(12 k) (135 + 49 k) + 6 E^(4 k) (243 + 61 k) + 
E^(16 k) (135 + 82 k) + E^(8 k) (1215 + 284 k)) == k
```

Where E is an exponential. In Maple, it's trivially done with Roots(function(k)=k,k,numeric) but in Mathematica, it takes too long to run.

Do you know how I can solve for k? Answer should be 0.2788....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need find approximated solutions previously.

From plot we can see that there are two solutions - near 0 and 0.2.

```
Plot[(1/((3 + E^(4 k))^8)) 
2 (1 + E^(4 k))^2 k (729 + E^(24 k) + 210 k + 
 2 E^(20 k) (9 + 7 k) + 4 E^(12 k) (135 + 49 k) + 
 6 E^(4 k) (243 + 61 k) + E^(16 k) (135 + 82 k) + 
 E^(8 k) (1215 + 284 k)) - k, {k, -1, 1}]
```

[image: plot.png]

You can use `FindRoot`.

```
FindRoot[(1/((3 + E^(4 k))^8))
2 (1 + E^(4 k))^2 k (729 + E^(24 k) + 210 k + 
  2 E^(20 k) (9 + 7 k) + 4 E^(12 k) (135 + 49 k) + 
  6 E^(4 k) (243 + 61 k) + E^(16 k) (135 + 82 k) + 
  E^(8 k) (1215 + 284 k)) == k, {k, 0.2}]
```

where `0.2` is our approximated solution. We obtain:

```
{k -> 0.278869}
```

Comment: It's good. But what if I didn't know the answer was near 0.2 ?

Comment: Like I'm sure Mathematica is on par with Maple, which it was able to do quickly. Was I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

You can restrict the calculation to real number solutions.  This solution took 0.1 seconds.

```
Timing[
 NSolve[(1/((3 + E^(4 k))^8)) 2 (1 + E^(4 k))^2 k (729 + E^(24 k) + 
      210 k + 2 E^(20 k) (9 + 7 k) + 4 E^(12 k) (135 + 49 k) + 
      6 E^(4 k) (243 + 61 k) + E^(16 k) (135 + 82 k) + 
      E^(8 k) (1215 + 284 k)) == k, k, Reals]]
```

> {0.109375, {{k -> 0.}, {k -> 0.278869}}}